# Accessing dictionary list complex data

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to manipulate data I got from an API response which I converted using `.json()`:

```
{
 'key1':'val1',
 'key2':'val2',
 'value':[
          {'K1':'V1',
           'K2':'V2',
           'K3':'V3'},
          {'K11':'V11',
           'K12':'V12',
           'K13':'V13'},
         ]
}
```

I want to construct a list of dictionaries like the following:

```
[{V2:{K1:V1, K3:V3}}, {V12:{K11:V11, K13:V13}}]
```

Edit: I determine V2 or V12 based on their respective key. The key is 'displayName' which is in every dictionary element in the list.

Comment: How do you know which value becomes the key in each new object?

Comment: From the key name (K2 and K12)

Comment: But how do you differentiate K2 from K3 in their respective roles?

Comment: Wait -- you've already converted the json to a dictionary, and need to manipulate it?  Or you need to know how to convert it to a dictionary, and then manipulate it?

Comment: @Raj please provide additional details to help us understand how you want to create these results. It is not inherently obvious how you go from your inputs to the outputs. One important item to know... Python Dictionaries are un-ordered, so K2 and K12, while they show up as the second item in each of the sub dictionaries you show may not be the second item in the dictionaries that Python creates.

Also, please provide any sample code you have generated to help achieve your goals.

Comment: 'K2' is a string, which want to use as an identifier. So even if the items are not in order, I can check if the key is 'K2'.

Comment: @BasyaPerlman I used the .json(0 on the raw response that I received and this is the output structure now and I want to manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

If the outer keys (`'K2'` and `'K12'`) are fixed in advance it can be as simple (*cough*) as using a conditional dictionary comprehension inside a list comprehension:

```
>>> [{subdict[op]: 
...   {key: value for key, value in subdict.items() if key != op}}
...  for op, subdict in zip(['K2', 'K12'], dct['value'])]
[{'V2': {'K1': 'V1', 'K3': 'V3'}}, {'V12': {'K11': 'V11', 'K13': 'V13'}}]
```

assuming your dictionary is stored in a variable called `dct`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you determine the keys but:

```
output = []

for sub_dict in d.get('value'):
    # assuming its always the middle element?
    nk = sub_dict.keys()[len(sub_dict.keys()) / 2]
    output.append({nk : {k:v for k,v in sub_dict.items() if k != nk}})

[{'K2': {'K1': 'V1', 'K3': 'V3'}}, {'K12': {'K11': 'V11', 'K13': 'V13'}}]
```